# rhel + any best practice to minimize the CLOSE_WAIT sessions from linux side

Tags: linux, rhel, netstat, port, ss

when we perform the following cli on our rhel machine we get more then 600 `CLOSE_WAIT` lines

```
lsof -i tcp:8088 | grep CLOSE_WAIT
java    31100 yarn  385u  IPv4 208022048      0t0  TCP master02.hgti.com:radan-http->master02.hgti.com:56504 (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    31100 yarn  407u  IPv4 208210692      0t0  TCP master02.hgti.com:radan-http->master02.hgti.com:58918 (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    31100 yarn  408u  IPv4 206182798      0t0  TCP master02.hgti.com:radan-http->master02.hgti.com:36538 (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    31100 yarn  410u  IPv4 208447279      0t0  TCP master02.hgti.com:radan-http->master02.hgti.com:60972 (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    31100 yarn  412u  IPv4 208287324      0t0  TCP master02.hgti.com:radan-http->master02.hgti.com:59820 (CLOSE_WAIT)
java    31100 yarn  413u  IPv4 206107964      0t0  TCP master02.hgti.com:radan-http->master02.hgti.com:35704 (CLOSE_WAIT)
.
.
.
.
.
```

as I know During the communication between the server and the client, the `closed_wait` caused by the socket failure of the server occurs

so any chance to do some settings from Linux side? in order to minimize the `close wait` sessions?

or its should be only solution from application side?

reference - https://www.programmersought.com/article/74221875444/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might a bug in your application, maybe you can keep it under control if you restart the application before running out of the maximum number of open files / sockets, or increase any artificial limits set by ulimit.

Try looking for a bug report, for example:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-9336
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-4754
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-10207

Or report one yourself (if this is your application). For a discussion of this type of issue, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912370/how-do-i-remove-a-close-wait-socket-connection